# Unable to connect to IBM MQ using pymqi

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am getting the below error while connecting to IBM MQ using library pymqi.

Its a clustered MQ channel

```
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2539: FAILED: MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR
```

Please see my code below.

```
queue_manager = "QMNAME"
channel = bytes(str("CHANNEL_NAME"))
host = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
port = "1800"
queue_name = "QN"
conn_info1 = bytes("%s(%s)" % (host, port))
message = b'{"alert":[{"timestamp":"Wed Jun 27 11:07:37 CDT 2018","shortDescription":"Last 24 hrs Sev 4 Volume Deviation is 84% lower than baseline","alertColor":"red","title":"Sev 4 Volume Deviation"}]}'

# Message Descriptor
put_mqmd = pymqi.MD()
qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info1)
queue = pymqi.Queue(qmgr, queue_name)
```

Getting error at the line below

```
qmgr = pymqi.connect(queue_manager, channel, conn_info1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause:

The `2539 (MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR)` error is a result of you attempting to connect to a channel on the queue manager that is not of type `SVRCONN`.  A MQ client must connect to a `SVRCONN` channel.

### Additional information:

If you review the queue manager error logs you would see corresponding `AMQ9502` errors, for example:

```
AMQ9502: Type of channel not suitable for action requested.

EXPLANATION:
The operation requested cannot be performed on channel 'CHANNEL_NAME'. Some
operations are only valid for certain channel types. This channel is a
'CLUSRCVR' channel type. For example, you can only ping or trigger a channel
from the initiating end.
ACTION:
Check whether the channel name is specified correctly.  If it is check that the
channel has been defined correctly.
```

### Resolution:

Make sure you have a `SVRCONN` channel defined on the queue manager you wish to connect to.

### Troubleshooting:

The MQ client comes with a sample program `amqscnxc`, you could use this to test out the parameters you have specified in your example.  For instance on Linux/Unix (quoting of the conname may be different on Windows) do the following:

```
amqscnxc -x 'xx.xx.xx.xx(1800)' -c CHANNEL_NAME QMNAME
```

The result would be the same `2539` error, but this does show it is not a pymqi specific problem.

Comment: So over here its CHLTYPE is CLUSRCVR so it will not be able to connect ?

Comment: That is correct, a `CLUSRCVR` channel's purpose is to allow other queue managers in a cluster to connect to it, not MQ clients.

Comment: @yasinmohammed check out "[MQ Essentials - Getting started with IBM MQ](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/getting-started-mq/)" for a nice free guide IBM has provided for those new to IBM MQ.

Comment: Thanks for the link I will check it out.